# Launching R help: Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I want to launch R help, I type `?dir.create`. It is giving me this strange error:

> Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(out, "wt") :
>
> cannot open file
> 'C:\Users\XYZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp86bEoJ\Rtxt32dcef24de2': No
> such file or directory

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Ok.Thank you all.I was able to resolve this by changing the directory and exiting R and re-logging into swirl.

Answer (score 88):

This happens when the temporary directory used by R is deleted. This usually happens when user or the system cleans up the tmp directory while the R session is running. Typically happens if the R session is open for a long time.

Remedy is very simple. You don't actually need to restart R. Just re-create the temporary directory by:

```
tempdir()
# [1] "C:\Users\XYZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp86bEoJ\Rtxt32dcef24de2"
dir.create(tempdir())
```

NOTE: this happens to me more and more often in Windows 10... even within like 8 hour session only! Not sure why this happens. See this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1502272/windows-10-cleaning-up-my-temp-dir-too-often

Comment: I never would have thought of that - you're a lifesaver.

Comment: Worked well for me. +1

Comment: Worked for me. I'll add that today is the first time I've see this problem and today I was playing with R's file.xxx() commands and fileSnapshot().

Comment: ...Actually, my history shows usage of only the following commands after R startup: getwd(), list.files(), basename(), dirname(), file.exists(), dir.exists(), file.info(), file.mtime(). That's when the error first appeared. Using RStudio.