# R studio gives error 'Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection' repeatedly while open

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running R studio 2022.07.01 using R version 4.2.1 on a windows PC using 64 bit.

While I have it open, I get this error message repeatedly
Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection

The error doesn't impact my code, it just pops up a lot and I have to hit ok.

It seems to be random.
I do set my working directory to somewhere on my C drive.

Is there anything I can do to make this stop?

I reset the directory to just setwd(C:/). Also I have closed R, cleared objects from the workspace, and done gc(). And restarted the computer.

Comment: Do you have a`.Rprofile` file?  If so, what does it do?

Comment: It'll be difficult to troubleshoot without better access. (1) Check the envvar `HOME` in the OS's environment variables and in R with `Sys.getenv("HOME")` to compare. (2) Check `.libPaths()` to see if all of those directories exist and are readable. They should all be local; while network drives can work, they can also introduce some problems such as latency or periodic unavailability. (3) Verify that both `%APPDATA%/RStudio` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%/RStudio` exist and are writeable by your user.

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 lib paths. One to my local user that I can write to, but the other is under C:/Program files/ and I can't write to this.   I typed rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables in the cmd prompt and then added this  Variable name: R_LIBS_USER 
Variable value: C:/users/.....R/win-library/4.2 . Even though the C:/Program Files lib path is still there, it seems like I have stopped getting the error message.

Comment: I am still getting this issue. It's wierd because it only happens when I am typing in R studio. The error never happens when R is just sitting idle.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57109052/5114585
It helped me but it's strange that sometimes I get this error even in a fresh session.
This is happening recently. Never seen R giving such trouble before.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I figured out another solution which is pulling and pushing to git at the beginning of a session. I'm running my computer with a VPN to my work office and I think the connection gets dropped sometimes. Maybe this affects git and the R session.